# Coloring a graph with no Monochromatic odd cycle/

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have this question in Graph Theory course, that I think I haven't understood well.
the question is:
Prove that the vertices of every connected graph on at least 8 vertices with maximum degree 6 can be colored with 3 colors so that no odd cycle is monochromatic.

I don't understand. If the graph contains K5 for example, or K4, there is no way I can color it with only 3 colors. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a requirement that adjacent vertices be colored differently, if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: So I can just color every odd cycle with 3 colors and all of the other nodes in some color of these 3..

Comment: Yes, I think that's what it means.  If the graph is bipartite, so it has no odd cycles, then you could color all the nodes the same, as I understand it.

Comment: I can prove it for maximum degree $5$, but not yet for maximum degree $6$. Nice question. Is it in the context of Ramsey theory?

Answer (score 1):

By [Brooks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem), since the graph has maximum degree $\le6$, is connected, and is not $K_7$, it has chromatic number $\le6$. Consider a proper vertex coloring with $6$ colors called red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet.

Now  consider a new vertex coloring with only $3$ colors (red, yellow, blue) obtained from the aforementioned proper coloring by recoloring the orange vertices red, the green vertices yellow, and the violet vertices blue.

Let $C$ be a monochromatic cycle in the new coloring; I claim that the length of $C$ must be even. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the vertices of $C$ are red in the new coloring. Therefore, in the original *proper* coloring, they were *alternately* red and orange. Therefore the length of $C$ is even.